# Writing this while-loop in for-loop

Tags: scala, stanford-nlp

I'm working with StanfordNLP to extract data from a parsed Tree.

I'm using Scala for coding.

```
val tp = TregexPattern.compile("SOME_PATTERN")
val res = tp.matcher("SOME_TREE")
```

to read the results of this I use

```
while (res.find()) {
  println(res.getMatch.getLeaves.mkString(" "))
}
```

I want to rewrite this while-loop in for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
val tp = TregexPattern.compile("SOME_PATTERN")
val res = tp.matcher("SOME_TREE")
for(it <- Iterator.continually(res.getMatch).takeWhile(_ => res.find)) {
  println(it.getLeaves.mkString(" "))
}
```

Comment: Works well, but the first result of `it` returned is a `null`, how to handle this?

Comment: something like this works `tags <- Iterator.continually(res.getMatch).takeWhile(_ => res.find) if tags != null` but is there a better way? or the whole code in another way?!

Comment: Put a "res.find" in front of the for loop to avoid getting null.